# Django: Unicode Filenames with ASCII headers?

Tags: python, django, unicode, nginx, ascii

I have a list of strangely encoded files: `02 - Charlie, Woody and You／Study #22.mp3` which I suppose isn't so bad but there are a few particular characters which Django OR nginx seem to be snagging on.

```
>>> test = u'02 - Charlie, Woody and You／Study #22.mp3'
>>> test
u'02 - Charlie, Woody and You\uff0fStudy #22.mp3'
```

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy to connect to django's built in webserver (still in development stages) and postgresql for my database.  My database and tables are all `en_US.UTF-8` and I am using pgadmin3 to view my tables outside of django.  My issue goes a little beyond my title, firstly how should I be saving possibly whacky filenames in my database?  My current method is

```
'path': smart_unicode(path.lstrip(MUSIC_PATH)),
'filename': smart_unicode(file)
```

and when I pprint out the values they do show `u'whateverthecrap'`

I am not sure if that is how I should be doing it but assuming it is now I have issues trying to spit out the download.

My download view looks something like this:

```
def song_download(request, song_id):
    song = get_object_or_404(Song, pk=song_id)
    url = u'/static_music/%s/%s' % (song.path, song.filename)

    print url

    response = HttpResponse()
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = url
    response['Content-Type'] = 'audio/mpeg'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=test.mp3"

    return response
```

and most files will download but when I get to `02 - Charlie, Woody and You／Study #22.mp3` I receive this from django: `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\uff0f' in position 118: ordinal not in range(128), HTTP response headers must be in US-ASCII format`.

How can I use an ASCII acceptable string if my filename is out of bounds?  `02 - Charlie, Woody and You\uff0fStudy #22.mp3` doesn't seem to work...

**EDIT 1**

I am using Ubuntu for my OS.

Comment: It's not clear to me if your forward slash character `/` is meant here to be part of the filename or the parent directory plus filename? (Because, of course, the forward slash character '/' is not allowed as part of a filename in most modern filesystems, due to the confusion with the directory structure.)

Nevertheless, to encode the forward slash in an ASCII-safe way, you could use '\u002f'... but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: It is more of a delimiter in this song, I am not sure how they got it in but it's not a true `/`, it's a `／` which is probably why it's allowed.  This was probably a poor example but it has done it on many other unicoded characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although `／` is an unusual and undesirable character, your script will break for *any* non-ASCII character.

```
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = url
```

`url` is Unicode (and it isn't a URL, it's a filepath). Response headers are bytes. You'll need to encode it.

```
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = url.encode('utf-8')
```

that's assuming you're running on a server with UTF-8 as the filesystem encoding.

(Now, how to encode the filename in the `Content-Disposition` header... that's an altogether trickier question!)

Comment: Haha sorry, url USE to be a url.  I'm running Ubuntu 10.4 (Beta), is there a way to tell my filesystem's encoding?

Comment: Yeah, unless you've changed it, Ubuntu will be UTF-8. Every modern OS except Windows uses UTF-8.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20933751/484127) `filename` parameter must always be ascii, e.g: `filename=test.encode('ascii', 'replace')`, while newer browsers (following [RFC-6266](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266)) can use `filename*`, e.g: `filename*=''urlquote(test)`.